# What is the best way for using Bootstrap in Angular CLI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

Which one is the best practice to use Bootstrap in Angular-Cli Project?

Using this method:
https://medium.com/@beeman/tutorial-add-bootstrap-to-angular-cli-apps-b0a652f2eb2

Or

Using ngx-bootstrap:
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way for me is:

- Create a project with `ng new`
- Install bootstrap, jquery and font-awesome with `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 jquery font-awesome`
- in your `.angular-cli.json`add:

  `"apps": [{
      "styles": [
          "styles.css",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]`

This will automatically compile the bootstrap css and javascript, font-awesome and jquery, which is required by the bootstrap js, in your index.html.

**Note**: The `jquery.min.js` under scripts must be included before the `bootstrap.min.js` is included, because `bootstrap.min.js` requires `jquery.min.js` to work properly.

**UPDATE:**
Bootstrap 4 requires tether.js. Install it with `npm install tether`and add it to your scripts in `.angular-cli.json`BEFORE bootstrap.min.js.

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering, i used your way but after ng serve i see error in my chrome console that says:  Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `ng-bootstrap` to `bootstrap` in any angular project.

Below is a comment taken from [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

*The goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript implementation for components. Nor should you include other dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code.*